# set standard recurring unit on contribution site

Tags: civicontribute, contribution-page, recurring-contributions

is there a way to set a standard for the dropdown of the recurring units (yearly, monthly, etc.) on a civi contribution site? We would like to have "yearly" instead of "monthly".

I tried to find sth in the configuration but apparently there is no easy way to do so.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The recurring configuration is present on contribution page under amount tab. There you can select the units that you want user to select when doing donation or payment.

The units supported by Civi are Year, Month, Week and Day

Doc: https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/contributions/online-contributions/#amounts-tab

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I am trying to change the default unit "monthly" to "yearly"

Comment: for the existing record you mean? i.e user who have on going recurring contribution

Comment: no.
i mean on the contribution site, when a new user wants to do a donation, the default recurring unit is "monthly", but i want to have "yearly" as default in the dropdown

Comment: I think you'd need to write a little extension. Take a look at https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_buildForm/#example where it sets a default. The field you want is `pledge_frequency_unit`.